# Tensorflow errors in Ubuntu Google Cloud Instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to run a demo script written in python inside a python 3.6 virtualenv on a Ubuntu 18 Google Cloud instance.

Flask and tensorflow 0.12 are installed.

When I run `python demo.py`, the following error comes up:

```
ImportError: cannot import name zip_longest
```

Other threads have suggested changing the code, but as this is a working demo I am wondering if there is something else going on.

Comment: Can you provide pip version and Flask version?

Comment: @J.LValtueña - Flask 1.0.2 pip 18.0  I also had to switch from venv to virtualenv, and run as python3 demo.py, but running on port 1995 brings up `Error: Malformed URL` in the browser and "this site can't be reached" when the URL is copy-pasted into another window. Using a Docker container helped, but didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: So now the zip_longest issue is resolved, right? Making it work by switching to python3 makes sense as the method for python 2 is actually [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest). As for the `Malformed URL` I would suggest that you edit your question adding the complete stack trace to show where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I solved it by reinstalling `six`

`pip uninstall six && pip install six` Try this if it is not working let me know.

Comment: still getting the import error for zip_longest after running `pip uninstall six && pip install six` in both the directory and in the virtualenv. Still not sure what's going on with itertools.